# arm-linux-gnueabihf cross compilation linking dynamic libraries

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I have pre-compiled binaries of the arm-linux-gnueabihf GCC toolchain. Host is x86_64 while the intended target is  arm7 architecture. I am able to cross compile a sample program using this cross-compiler but it is not able to link with dynamic libraries. On the host, I use:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf -c -o test test.c
```

The compiled executable with ldd command shows following output on host as well as target:

```
ldd ./test
     not a dynamic executable
```

However, I use the same source code and compile natively on the target, I observe:

```
ldd ./test
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e29000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f18000)
```

The whole concept of linker seems tricky in case of cross-compilation. Is there a standard way to link shared dynamic libraries while cross compiling?

Comment: Same problem here. did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes. In my case, the files were cross-compiled and linked correctly. The issue was with the transfer of executable over TFTP. It seems the target Linaro (Ubuntu) strips off some of the bytes on receiving the file over TFTP.